# DateTime.ParseExact string format keeps throwing error

Tags: .net, datetime

I have a string representation of DateTime that looks like this:

```
2011-05-25T16:42:17.156Z
```

I have tried the following without any luck:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(formatted, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime.ParseExact(formatted, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime.ParseExact(formatted, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
DateTime.ParseExact(formatted, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

All of these give the error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Standard DateTime.Parse appears to work, though for performance reasons we are exploring ParseExact.  This seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use HH instead of hh for 24 hour format. This should work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(formatted, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ",
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Are you *sure* you want to use the current culture rather than the invariant culture though?

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion, and have tested it already. With `HH` it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.  Why would one choose invariant culture over current culture? or vice versa?

Comment: @user90070: Using the invariant culture would give the same result regardless of the current culture. Some of the separators in the date format are culture dependant, so it might not work for all cultures. Another alternative is to use apostrophes around the separators to make the format string culture independant; `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffZ"`.

Comment: Specifying an exact ISO 8601 date/time format (culture-invariant by design, using Gregorian calendar) and then supplying a locale does seem a bit redundant. Not all locales use the Gregorian calendar or even have calendars with 12 months in a year, though: perhaps they're representing local date/time using ISO 8601 syntax. Israel, perhaps? They've got either 12 or 13 months per year.) The `MM` format specifier, as I understand it, is supposed to deal with 12/13 months per year, if the locale's calendar supports it.

Comment: @Nicholas: Yes, that's a possibility - but I *suspect* that's not actually wanted in this case, and explicitly specifying the invariant culture takes any doubt out of the matter :)