# Convert Oracle Date to c# DateTime

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am trying to read a record from oracle database of type Date and then convert it to ASP.NET c# DateTime object. Problem is, it picks up the date but not the time. Command I'm using is:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

If I try to print `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()` then it shows the time as well. Anyone know how to get around this?

My oracle date field has a value/format of:`2013-01-01 14:14:14`

Comment: You can check this [SO solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6128000/125551) and use DateTime.ParseExact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

parses using specified format and does not depend on thread culture.

Answer (score 8):

Everyone else is overcomplicating it.

Oracle Managed Data Access (which I assume you're using) returns dates as the "OracleDate" type. OracleDate has a property "Value" which is a c# DateTime.

In my case, to get a DateTime from an out parameter (p2 below), I used

```
return ((OracleDate) p2.Value).Value;
```

For Op's case where the date in question is in a row of the returned dataset, use

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
```

edit: if taking data from a DataRow, for some reason the date will actually be a c# DateTime

Comment: I arrived here looking for help getting a C# DateTime from the date returned from OracleCommand.ExecuteScalar(). You pointed me in the right direction. Thanks! My code ended up being thus:  DateTime OriginalEntryDate = ((OracleDate)cmd.ExecuteScalar()).Value;

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't just use `DateTime.Parse()`? Taking in the database value seemed to give the correct output (with the time included which seems to be what you're after)

[image]

Comment: DateTime.Parse() is culture-dependant, so it can produce different results for you and @Bagzli

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().First().Field<DateTime>(0);
```

should do the job

Answer (score 0):

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["mydate"].ToString());

I try it successfully.