# Oracle DateTime to C# Date time

Tags: c#, oracle

I am returning utc date time from my stored procedure, like this

```
 SELECT CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS DATE) INTO utc_date FROM DUAL;
```

I am returning it in Out parameter of my sp, the out parameter type is TimeStamp, since I want time as well.
This is how I am getting the returned parameter from sp

```
 DbParameter param25 = GetDbParameter("my_utc_date" , DbType.DateTime2 , DBNull.Value);
                            param25.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            param25.Size = 100;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(param25);
```

now I want to convert the value of param25 to date time, I tried this,but its giving me format exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
  DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(param25.Value), "d/M/yyyy" , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

I tried using DbType.DateTime too, but same error.

I am getting this value in param.Value,

```
17-OCT-17 07.07.35.000000 AM
```

How can I convert oracle datetime to c# datetime,with time as well.

Comment: Well the format you showed is d-M-yyy hh.mm.ss.ffffff perhaps you should try that as your format string as you have no "/" in your date

Comment: I tried using d-M-yyy,but still the same issue

Comment: With ParseExact (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) you have to give a format, you give `d/M/yyyy` but it should be something like `dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.FFFFF tt`

Comment: Also take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings this is where you find all the formats

Comment: @BugFinder `M` is the month from 1 to 12, he has `OCT` this is `MMM`

Comment: d-M-yyyy doesnt account for all the sections you have and EpicKip is right it would need tt on the end for the am/pm

Comment: also have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/16596231/7449966

Comment: @EpicKip true but we need a mix of us both as F is for non zero so its f :P  however theres more than enough for salman to try work some of it out himself

Comment: @Salman *sigh* You need to enter the format to convert the string to datetime.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @BugFinder Did not know F is non zero, thanks for teaching me something :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How convert string to Datetime by a format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103970/how-convert-string-to-datetime-by-a-format)

Comment: Your code is useless. You receive a `DateTime` value, convert it to a `String` and then convert back again to `DateTime`. Simply make `DateTime dt = param25.Value;` `DateTime2` does not make sense either as Oracle `DATE` precision is only up to second.

Comment: Date and DateTime have no display format.  
What you see is only the default string representation of the DateTime value. You should be able to use `Convert.ToDateTime`: `var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(param25.Value);`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I tried it too(DateTime dt = param25.Value;), it is  giving me compile time error of explicit conversion

Comment: @ZoharPeled I tried it too but its giving me format exceptioj

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Oracle, but I know it has a `to_char` method that can be used to convert datetime values to a specific display format. You can use that with your desired format and then `DateTime.ParseExact` on the c# side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this one:

```
var param25 = new OracleParameter("my_utc_date", OracleDbType.Date);
param25.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param25.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param25);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

var result = param25.Value;
// or -> DateTime result = (DateTime)param25.Value;
```

`.Size` is not required for DateTime types. Note, for `OracleParameter` you have property `OracleDbType` and `DbType`. Their defaults are `VARCHAR2`, resp. `String`, that is the reason why you get back a string instead of a DATE value.