# Different output for a simple oracle select query when executed from PL/SQL Developer and .Net

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle19c, ora-01858

I need to obtain the last date of the month without time component of sysdate. When I execute the following query in PL/SQL Developer it returns the correct answer

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) Last_Date 
from dual
```

[image: PL/SQL Developer Output]

However when I execute the above select query in .NET I'm getting the following error:

[image: .Net WinForms Output]

I created a Winforms application and execute the Oracle query and print the result with a label tool.

Winforms C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(getConnectionString()))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd_2 = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;

                cmd_2.Connection = con;
                cmd_2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd_2.CommandText = "select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) Last_Date from dual";

                con.Open();
                cmd_2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                label1.Text = dt.ToString(); ;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the Winforms code to get the same result as the PL/SQL Developer. Please suggest how to fix my code for both Oracle & .NET.

PS: this is related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77774325/getting-ora-01858-exception-when-an-oracle-stored-procedure-executed-from-winfor)

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a select statement, but you use the "ExecuteNonQuery" command.  This is only for inserts, updates, etc.

To read data from the DB then you need to use the `ExecuteReader()` command,  something like this;

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) Last_Date from dual", connection);
con.Open();
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
try
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        myVarToSet = reader.GetValue(0);
    }
}
finally
{
    reader.Close();
}
```

Note that this also uses OracleCommand and not OleDb, which would be better.

Or as in your case you are only returning a single item from a single row, you would actually be better off to use `ExecuteScalar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```sql
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) Last_Date 
from dual
```

Will:

1. find today's date-and-time - `SYSDATE`
2. find the equivalent date-and-time for the last day of the month - `LAST_DAY(...)`
3. convert that date to a string using the format model `DD-MON'YYYY` - `TO_CHAR(..., 'DD-MON-YYYY')`
4. convert the string back to a date implicitly using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the format model - `TO_DATE(...)`

You should **NEVER** rely on implicit conversions as if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` changes then your query will fail (which appears to be what is happening here).

In this particular case, the last two steps are pointless as you are converting a date to a string and then immediately back to a date (about the only thing it would do is to truncate the time component of the date back to midnight).

You could simplify your code to:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) AS Last_Date FROM DUAL
```

or, since you are going to ignore the time component of the `DATE`, then:

```sql
SELECT LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) AS Last_Date FROM DUAL
```

Would also work.

---

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

When the result of the query gets sent to the client application (either PL/SQL Developer or .Net) then the database will send the binary value to that client application  and the client **displays** the date to you the user. The database does not know anything about how the client displays the date, it just sends the binary value and lets the client do what it is programmed to do.

If you want to change how the client formats dates then either:

- Explicitly tell the client how to convert the binary `DATE` value to a string when it displays it

  - In PL/SQL developer there will be something in the preferences/settings for the client that defines the format model used to format dates.
  - In .Net, you can read the query's value (which you do not do as you use `cmd_2.ExecuteNonQuery();` for a query and ignore the result set) and [read the value as a `DateTime`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16596231/1509264) and use `your_date_time_variable.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` to [format it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).
- Alternatively, do not send a `DATE` and explicitly format the string in the query:

  ```sql
  SELECT TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS Last_Date FROM DUAL
  ```

  Then neither client has to format the string as it is already formatted by the database.